# What is mean "x" in second field of /etc/shadow file

Tags: linux, password, shadow

I have content in shadow file:

```bsh
root:!:17777::::::
bin:x:14871::::::
daemon:x:14871::::::
mail:x:14871::::::
ftp:x:14871::::::
http:x:14871::::::
dbus:x:14871::::::
nobody:x:14871::::::
systemd-journal-gateway:x:14871::::::
systemd-timesync:x:14871::::::
systemd-network:x:14871::::::
systemd-bus-proxy:x:14871::::::
systemd-resolve:x:14871::::::
systemd-journal-remote:!!:17635::::::
systemd-coredump:!!:17635::::::
uuidd:!!:17635::::::
dnsmasq:!!:17635::::::
rpc:!!:17635::::::
ntp:!:17635:0:99999:7:::
usbmux:!:17635:0:99999:7:::
avahi:!!:17635::::::
colord:!!:17635::::::
cups:!!:17635::::::
git:!!:17635::::::
lightdm:!!:17635::::::
nm-openconnect:!!:17635::::::
nm-openvpn:!!:17635::::::
polkitd:!!:17635::::::
rtkit:!!:17635::::::
qwerty:$6$4b0Rmzt4U9I6zbhV$zWtNjLeqSYTOrWagic0L10PSNwVuOTCcWD:17802:0:99999:7:::
gluster:!!:17798::::::
minidlna:!!:17818::::::
acestream:!:17861:0:99999:7:::
postgres:!:17892:0:99999:7:::
pgbouncer:!:17892::::::
geoclue:!!:17946::::::
```

I saw this question - [What means * and ! at second field of /etc/shadow?](https://superuser.com/questions/623881/what-means-and-at-second-field-of-etc-shadow). But there is no explanation what "x" is in the second field of shadow file.

I saw this question - [In /etc/group what is the meaning of the second field?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46514/in-etc-group-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-second-field). I'm not sure what files `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` have same convention.

Comment: @muru It's a dupe if the convention for `/etc/shadow` is the same as for `/etc/group` (referred to in the proposed dupe).

Comment: @Kusalananda that would then depend on which OS they're using, I suppose.

Comment: The second field is supposed to contain a hashed password or is empty (no password). If it contains something that can't be a hashed password, it means you can't log in. Hashed passwords are usually rather long, any one or two character entry is an impossible password, login forbidden. Some systems may assign extra meaning to the exact string, however.

Answer (score 4):

The standard documentation from `man shadow` should be installed on your system. On my Debian system it explains it like this:

> Each line of this file contains 9 fields, separated by colons ("`:`"),
>   in the following order:
>
> **login name**
>
> It must be a valid account name, which exist on the
>   system.
>
> **encrypted password**
>
> Refer to `crypt`(3) for details on how this string is interpreted.
>
> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of `crypt`(3), for instance `!` or `*`, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).
>
> This field may be empty, in which case no passwords are required to authenticate as the specified login name. However, some applications which read the `/etc/shadow` file may decide not to permit any access at all if the password field is empty.
>
> A password field which starts with an exclamation mark means that the password is locked. The remaining characters on the line represent the password field before the password was locked.
>
> [...]

In your case, the `x` in the second field corresponds to the description of "*some string that is not a valid result of `crypt`(3)*" in the documentation extract above.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is not a hashed password, so its presence disables login by that username

the ! on root has the same effect but it can be removed using `usermod`.

An empty password column allows log-in with no password, so these filler symbols are needed.